# UITable view and UIView in view controller scrollable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a question related to design for iOS using Swift.
I'm still new in this platform and also new to stack overflow.
Actually I've a view controller where inside it, There is UIView and Table view. There is UIView on top of half of the screen and the table view is start at half bottom of the view controller. I want the UITable view can be scroll to the top screen of view controller. I've already search at google, But it seems I do not know the term and keyword of this kind of design type. or is it any library that can design like this?.

the situation is describe in the image below:

[Initial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF8wV.png)

become:

[Second view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJnyM.png)
(after scroll)

Comment: Use tableview header instead of this.

Comment: @Lenin can i add UIImage, UICollection view and others inside the header?

Comment: Looking for this https://medium.com/@jeremysh/creating-a-sticky-header-for-a-uitableview-40af71653b55

Comment: Yes, you can add.

Comment: https://github.com/inforeqd512/StickyTableHeader
or
https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader (with cocoapods install)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this result by using header view in your `UITableView`. You can implement it by using `UITableViewDelegate` methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

Hope it helps.